# how to coverage this method on the class test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, developer

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, object> botaoExportarNovo(Map<String, object> btnExportar){
    Map<String, object> mapaObj = new Map<String, object>(); 
    CaseExpCsvController controller = new CaseExpCsvController();

    try{   
        controller.lInicio = Date.valueOf((String)btnExportar.get('dataInicio'));
        controller.lfim = Date.valueOf((String)btnExportar.get('dataFinal'));
        controller.lAtualizar = Boolean.valueOf(btnExportar.get('lAtualizar'));
        controller.lFltTipoCaso = String.valueOf(btnExportar.get('lFltTipoCaso'));
        controller.lFltStatusCaso = String.valueOf(btnExportar.get('lFltStatusCaso'));
        controller.llCsvGerado = true;
        controller.botaoExportar();
        mapaObj.put('lSelect', controller.ldisplay);

    }catch(exception e){ 
        controller.errors.add(e.getMessage());
    }
    mapaObj.put('Errors', controller.errors);
    return mapaObj;
}
```

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far? It currently looks like you want community to write test classe for you?

Comment: It's always better to ask not "how can I cover these lines of code?", but "how can I test these lines of code?" Coverage comes with real tests.  You can test this method like any other - call it from your test class with appropriate values, and make assertions about the results.

Comment: Hi Thiago S. Welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code.

Answer (score 1):

In an apex unit test an @Auraenabled method is just like any other controller method. You can just call it with the required params and validate the result.

```
//Setup Data
Map<String, object> btnExportar = new Map<String, object>();
//Populate the btnExportar map with the values you expect in a happy 
//path

//Call Method
Map<String, object> result = botaoExportarNovo(btnExportar);

//Validate the results
//Go through the map and validate the key value pairs
```

You should probably run a couple scenarios:
 - happy path (where it doesn't go in the catch block, probably validating an empty map)
 - exception path (where you should some errors in the map)